# How to show has many relation record in Yii2 GridView?

Tags: join, gridview, yii2

I am new in yii2. I have three tables? `s(id,firstName,lastName)` , `p(id,name)` and `sp(sid,pid,qty)`. there are all relation in s model(created by gii).
I want to show follow query in gridview by active record:

```
select s.firstName,s.lastName, sp.qty from s join sp on s.s#=sp.s#
```

and it returns below result:

> firstname1 lastname1 qty1
>
> firstname1 lastname1 qty2
>
> firstname2 lastname2 qty3

and for this reason I've wrote follow codes.

codes:

```
class SController extends Controller
{
    public function actionIndex()
    {


        $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' =>s::find(),

        ]);

        return $this->render('index', [
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        ]);
    }
}
```

and in index view:

```
<?= GridView::widget([
'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
'columns' => [
    ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],


    'firstName',
    'lastName',

   [

            'attribute' => 'quantity',
            'value' => function ($data) {

                if ($data->sps) {

                    return implode(\yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::map($data->sps, 'id','qty'));
                }

            },
        ],

    ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
],
```

]);

but it returns follow result:

> firstname1 lastname1 qty1qty2
>
> firstname2 lastname2 qty3

I dont know what is the problem?

Comment: if the query return the value you need  why you implode the result for qty .? .

Comment: I want just show the result in gridview in three rows. but i can't.

Comment: if you want separated  rows you should manage the dataProvider .. before showing the result in gridview  .. the gridview  (mainly) just show the content on the dataProvider

Comment: how to do it? sorry! I am new in yii2.

Comment: If you are new then first, you need to generate the SearchModel for the `s` and then use it inside the controller to return the `$dataProvider` to be used inside the gridview. this is the conventional way how yii works with gridview